# InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, error-handling

Below is the error I'm getting after trying to launch my main activity.

```
Process: com.example.weihao.cannongame, PID: 28156
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.weihao.cannongame/com.example.weihao.cannongame.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at com.example.weihao.cannongame.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at com.example.weihao.cannongame.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 69120012 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3737)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:244)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:240)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
        at com.example.weihao.cannongame.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is the XML code I have for my main Activity to be launched first by the application:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Menu"
    android:background="@drawable/bgmenu">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Play"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_marginTop="93dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/play"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Easy"
        android:id="@+id/easy"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium"
        android:id="@+id/medium"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hard"
        android:id="@+id/hard"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</RadioGroup>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Main java code for the application:

```
package com.example.weihao.cannongame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Wei Hao on 7/25/2015.
 */
public class Menu extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener {

    TextView title;
    RadioGroup rg;
    Button play;
    String d;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        play=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Bundle basket=new Bundle();
        basket.putString("key",d);
        Intent a=new Intent(Menu.this,mbb.class);
        a.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int arg1) {

        switch (arg1){
            case R.id.easy:
                d ="e";
                break;
            case R.id.medium:
                d ="m";
                break;
            case R.id.hard:
                d ="h";
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my XML code that causes this error to occur? Thanks.

Comment: is these your all xml ?

Comment: That is the xml file for my main Activity which the application will first launch....though i have other xml files as well

Comment: I don't know you forget to post or mistaken delete that code. But did you mention **rg** in your code before 
>rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

Comment: Yup it was declared at the beginning of the class

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have to use a root container element like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, etc.

Your first element is a TextView, which is not a valid container element for others UI items.

Comment: Actually my xml code is already enclosed in a relativelayout element but I'm not sure why it is not reflected here

Comment: Please update your post to show up the whole XML layout.

Comment: Ok, the xml structure seems good now. Try to add the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Hmmm I've tried adding it to the first line above the Relative Layout but the same error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these is proper xml file. As per my knowledge Mostly xml files start with

> ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?
>
> LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

these but i can't see such thing in your code. Please try to insert that and then check may help you.

Comment: Now you can post your Java code also so we can check both. 
Is it possible to you to post your respected java code?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured it out. It was due to a variety of reasons. Firstly, the background image i used is probably too large which causes the error. Secondly, I did not declare the RadioGroup properly by identifying them with their ids.

Thanks for the input guys